# How to get out of the loop, if the PHP script takes more than 53 seconds to execute

Tags: php, mysql, json, cron

In Short: How to break the code after the code takes more than 53 seconds to execute, something like this:

```
while (5 < 200)
{
// do some work here, which will take around 1-6 seconds

if (code this loop is running for more than 53 seconds)
break;

}
```

---

If you want to know, why i want to do this:

Ok, this is What I am doing: I am copying data from 7 JSON pages on the web and inserting them into my MySQL database.

The code is something like this:

```
$start_time = microtime(TRUE); // Helps to count PHP script execution time 


connect to database
$number = get inserted number into database
while ($number > ($number+20) )

{

7 Open JSON File link like this  - "example.com/$number?api=xxxyyzz"

Use Prepared PDO statements to insert data into MySQL

}
// Code to count PHP script execution time 
$end_time = microtime(TRUE);

$time_taken = $end_time - $start_time;

$time_taken = round($time_taken,5);

echo '<p>Page generated in '.$time_taken.' seconds.</p>';
```

So in my case, It takes around 5.2 seconds to complete one whole loop of adding all data. But some JSON files are empty, so it takes only 1.4 second to complete 1 loop, if they are empty.

So like that, I want to complete millions of loops (add Data from millions of JSON files). So if my code runs for 24/7, it will take me 1 month to complete my task.

---

But after the code runs for 90 seconds, i get this error: [image]

I am using a CRON job to do the task. And looks like server gives the same error to CRON job.

So, I want to do the CRON job to run every 1 minute, so I do not get timed out error.

---

But I am afraid of this: What If the script added data in half rows  and 1 mintue gets over, and it do not add data into other half rows. Then after the starting on the new minute, the code start from the next `$number`.

So, If i can `break;` out of the loop after 53 seconds (If the code starts another loop at 52 seconds, then break at the end of it, that will be around 58-59 seconds).

I mean,  i will put the break; code just before the loop end (before `}`). So i do not exit the loop, while the data got inserted into half of the rows.

Comment: I think you may use sleep function at place of break function.

Comment: Sleep function delay the code execution time, right? How can it save me from server 500 error? @AvinashKumarSingh bro?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your PHP's `max_execution_time` is equal to 90 seconds, you can  specify `max_execution_time` by `set_time_limit`, but I don't think it is a  good approach for this.

Have a try `pcntl` or `pthreads`, it would save you a lot of time.